# byte by byte dynamic audio processing in android studio

Tags: java, android, audio

I want to process audio byte by byte in Android Studio while streaming the song in real time. Can't seem to get the data from the MediaPlayer class. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please, add some code.

Comment: I haven't written any. just figuring out how to go about it. how to extract the stream of data that is to be played next. This is the problem as of now.

Comment: So ... you haven't tried *anything*, before coming here?

Answer (score 0):

instead of MediaPlayer use `AudioRecord` 
[Audio Record - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

sample:

```
int sampleRate = 16000;
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            bufferSize);
audioRecord.startRecording();        
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mIsRecording) {
            short[] buffer = new short[mBufferSize];
            int readSize = mAudioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // do your stuff here
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Will this not read the audio from mic? I need to read the data from the playing mp3 or wav files on the handset.

Comment: If you already have a audio files. you can 'read the file data'. isn't it?
Is your question is how to decode audio file and then processing byte by byte?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I am looking for. TIA.